# I migrate my database in flask I have Error: Self-loop is detected in revisions (3ce1c8043414) this error in migration process

Tags: python, database, flask-sqlalchemy

`$ flask db migrate` INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl. INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL. ERROR [flask_migrate] Error: Self-loop is detected in revisions (3ce1c8043414)``

`I want to migrate database, how to solve this.`

Answer (score 0):

Funny you post this today - I literally just had the same issue.  I ran `flask db edit <REF>`; in your case `flask db edit 3ce1c8043414`.  This opened up an editor with the revision and down_revision.  They were one and the same!  Hence the loop.  I just edited the revision id to be different and then ran `flask db migrate` - not guaranteed it'll solve *all* your issues, but it will get you past the loop. Good luck!